# How to know the Orientation of a Page before we had PageOrientation LandscapeRight/LandscapeLeft?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

In Windows Phone 8.0 we had `PageOrientation` with `LandscapeLeft`, `LandscapeRight` and more. Now, we only have `ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Orientation` and `DisplayProperties.CurrentOrientation`, but both of these only tell me if my page is `Horizontal` or `Vertical`. Does anyone know how to reproduce the `LandscapeLeft` and `LandscapeRight` we had in Windows Phone 8?

When a user rotates the page of my application (Windows Phone 8.1 XAML) I need to know if he has rotated the application `Clockwise` or `CounterClockwise` anyone have a idea how I could do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking I think I may have found a solution but it might not be the best solution:

Using

```
 DisplayProperties.OrientationChanged += Page_OrientationChanged;
```

We are able to see when the page is being rotated, 
then in this method we get the new orientation using DisplayProperties.CurrentOrientation:

```
 private void Page_OrientationChanged(object sender)
        {
            DisplayOrientations orientation = DisplayProperties.CurrentOrientation;

switch (orientation )
            {
                case DisplayOrientations.Landscape:
                    bla();
                    break;
                case DisplayOrientations.LandscapeFlipped:
                    blabla();
                    break;    
                case DisplayOrientations.Portrait:
                    MoreBla();
                    break;
                case DisplayOrientations.PortraitFlipped:
                    MoreBlaBla();
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Here we are able to know if the page has been rotated into Landscape, LandscapeFlipped, Portrait and or PortraitFlipped.